# I'd like to implement login and register in electron atom desktop app

Tags: electron

I will like to implement login and register function in electron atom desktop app
I'm a newbie just trying to play around electron atom
I'd like to learn electron by building a desktop app

Comment: your login and register must be done in html and javascript. nothing more complex than that

Answer (score 0):

You need a database to manage user accounts properly.

I'd recommend a web-server on which you would try to logon using a ajax request. The server response would then be your login failure or success. The response on the server could be written in PHP, Node.js or whatever you want, but since you're using electron i would suggest using a http response.

You could also use a local database like nosql or simply store your information into a local JSON File, but the user could simply edit this database. So its not recommented at all.

But i'd not recommend to start with a login at all. This requires more than just the basics.